# Progress Bar Dialog minimizes the main form

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am new to .NET desktop based development so please pardon me if I am missing some minor thing.

I have a Main form on which when user clicks a button, a dialog form is opened where user can select some files, after selecting the files, user clicks Process button on this form to start a lengthy process.
So what I have done is on clicking the button, I hide this form and initiate a backgroundworker and also start showing another dialog to show an animated progress bar image.
The problem that I am facing is when user clicks Process button, the form is hidden and progress bar dialog is shown but the main form gets minimized. Can any body help me in it? I don't want the main form to get minimized.

My code of the dialog where files are being selected is as:

```
frmProgressbar progressDialog = null;

private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    progressDialog = new frmProgressbar();
    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
            worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    progressDialog.ShowDialog();
}
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Do the lengthy work
}
void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    progressDialog.Close();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't get minimized.  You call Hide() but then you forget to call Show() again in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Comment: The above code is not of the main form, it is of the dialog where user is selecting the file, so I am calling Hide() to hide the dialog not the main form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to provide the parent form to the ShowDialog method

```
progressDialog.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: It worked for me but I didn't understand that what I have done, can you please provide a little bit information on it? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't explain. I just know this side effect of unowned dialog box. There are the other side effects related to the DialogBox() without parent.

Comment: right, no worries, I will find the information from my friends, "Search Engines" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
     private Thread progressThread;

 private void Btn_Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        progressThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ShowProgressWindow));
        progressThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
        progressThread.Start(); 

     // do your operation here...
        Class_Upload_SSRD.Search_All_Ptags(Cbox_Ptag_names, label4);
  ///close porcess once ur work is done...
        progressThread.Abort();
        Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
        this.Show();
    }
```

// progress bar function

```
   public void ShowProgressWindow()
    {
        Progress_bar pb = new Progress_bar();
        pb.ShowDialog();
    }
```

create progress window form ,it will be visible as shown in image when operation is being perfoemed
[image]